# Links in Dialog with text gets focus changes

Tags: android, dialog, hyperlink

I created a simple way to show a dialog with links inside. These links should be clickable, and all works pretty good.

But the issue is that all text now reacts on touch, making normal text flicker when touched.

```
 private void showDialogWithLinks(final String title, final SpannableString content, final String negativeButtonTitle) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Linkify.addLinks(content, Linkify.ALL);
    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(content)
            .setNegativeButton(negativeButtonTitle,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    try {
        alert.show();
        ((TextView)alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Anybody have a simple solution for this?

BR / Henric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced try-catch with the following:

```
        try {
        alert.show();
        TextView contentView = ((TextView)alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message));
        contentView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); // Makes sure the links are opened
        contentView.setTextColor(contentView.getCurrentTextColor()); // This is to remove focus on main text
    } catch (Exception e) {
        finish();
    }
```

This is to remove the ColorStateList being used, and only using the main color. Hence removing unwanted behavior on text color.

Hopes this helps someone as well :)

BR / Henric

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue on devices running Gingerbread. I fix it by using AlertDialog.Builder with "**setItems**".

```
    final CharSequence[] items = { "item1", "item2", "item3"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Options for ");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
            // OnClick
        }
    }).show();
```

Comment: It does show the text, but links are not opened upon touch. This did not do the trick.